# Getting errors frequently in magento2

Tags: magento2

I migrated the database of magento 1.9.x website to magento 2 using the `data-migration-tool`. After migrating the database the products and categories are displayed at the backend. Now when I cleared my cache am getting an error like

> There has been an error processing your request Exception printing is
>   disabled by default for security reasons. Error log record number:
>   1863159107

in both frontend and backend. This error is happening for even a small change made at backend or frontend(clearing cache, redindexing) and when I run the command `php magento setup:static-content:deploy` Its getting error like `more than one default website is defined`. Someone please help me regarding this issue. 
The error in `1863159107` is

```
 a:4:{i:0;s:40:"More than one default website is defined";i:1;s:2115:"#0   C:\xampp\htdocs\mage2.0.4\vendor\magento\module- store\Model\StoreResolver\Website.php(46):  Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteRepository->getDefault()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage2.0.4\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\StoreResolver.php(130): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver\Website->getAllowedStoreIds(NULL)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage2.0.4\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\StoreResolver.php(116): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->readStoresData()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage2.0.4\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\StoreResolver.php(85): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getStoresData()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage2.0.4\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\StoreManager.php(151): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getCurrentStoreId()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage2.0.4\vendor\magento\module-store\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor.php(39): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getStore('')
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage2.0.4\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor.php(47): Magento\Store\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), '/')
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage2.0.4\var\generation\Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy.php(95): Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), '/')
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage2.0.4\vendor\magento\framework\App\Request\Http.php(161): Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy->process(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), '/')
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage2.0.4\vendor\magento\framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request.php(194): Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http->setPathInfo()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage2.0.4\vendor\magento\framework\App\Request\Http.php(204): Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request->getPathInfo()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage2.0.4\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(110): Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http->getFrontName()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage2.0.4\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage2.0.4\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#14 {main}";s:3:"url";s:11:"/mage2.0.4/";s:11:"script_name";s:20:"/mage2.0.4/index.php";}
```

Not only this issue, In magento 2 when I try to change some style in frontend,the styles are getting lost and page is displayed like below
[image]

why is this happening?

Comment: Please check your browser console for any error

Comment: What's the content of the `var/report/1863159107` file ?

Comment: I have edited my question. Kindly see it.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same error on a multi-website project and it seems if you change the default website's name to anything other than `Main Website`, Magento creates a new store record, but keeps the old one!

The exception is thrown in this file *./vendor/magento/module-store/Model/WebsiteRepository.php*

```
private function initDefaultWebsite()
{
    $websites = (array) $this->getAppConfig()->get('scopes', 'websites', []);
    foreach ($websites as $data) {
        if (isset($data['is_default']) && $data['is_default'] == 1) {
            if ($this->default) {
                throw new \DomainException(__('More than one default website is defined'));
            }
    // ...
```

Dumping out the contents of `$websites` I found

```
Array
(
    [admin] => Array
        (
            [website_id] => 0
            [code] => admin
            [name] => Admin
            [sort_order] => 0
            [default_group_id] => 0
            [is_default] => 0
        )

    [base] => Array
        (
            [website_id] => 1
            [code] => base
            [name] => Main Website
            [sort_order] => 0
            [default_group_id] => 1
            [is_default] => 1
        )

    [wholesale] => Array
        (
            [website_id] => 2
            [code] => wholesale
            [name] => Wholesale
            [sort_order] => 2
            [default_group_id] => 2
            [is_default] => 0
        )

    [retail] => Array
        (
            [website_id] => 1
            [code] => retail
            [name] => Retail
            [sort_order] => 0
            [default_group_id] => 1
            [is_default] => 1
        )

)
```

Notice, `base` and `retail` both have `is_default` set... Changing the name of the default website back to `Main Website` seems to have fixed the problem as the last record went away when doing so.

In conclusion, the `Main Website` is magical and should not be renamed from what I can tell.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue. Can you tell me _where_ the name of the default website needs to be set/changed?

Comment: @MarkBiek Under `Stores -> All Stores`, then click the name of the default website if it isn't currently named 'Default Website' and change it to 'Default Website'.

Comment: Unfortunately, this error is preventing me from even getting into the admin. Is it possible to do it from the command-line (or directly in the database)?

Comment: Found it! I needed to make the change in `app/etc/config.local.php`.

Comment: ahh, so that's how you can change the name of the default website - nice find!

Comment: In my case, I just made `Main Website` _not_ a default anymore and that did the trick.